# Groovy to collect and remove duplicates from a complex json structure

Tags: recursion, search, groovy

this is my first question at Stack Overflow, so, firstly, Hello colleagues and many thanks in advance.

I have this json input message I'm dealing with,  but I cannot find the key to get the message I need for further processing

```
    {
  "callId": "70f354ed47e643bc9d1cd6595e018f9b",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusReason": "OK",
  "time": "2022-08-01T07:56:34.631Z",
  "results": [
    {
      "UID": "5abc8d08d8e148158610c7c6776c4ad5",
      "groups": {
        "organizations": [
          {
            "businessModels": [
              {
                "keys": [
                  "Company Code",
                  "Sales Org",
                  "Distribution Channel",
                  "Division"
                ],
                "businessEntities": [
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50",
                      "HU50_HU50",
                      "HU50_HU50_10",
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "id": "SalesArea_161185"
              },
              {
                "keys": [
                  "ShiptoInc_SalesArea",
                  "ShiptoInc_Id"
                ],
                "businessEntities": [
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10",
                      "100563692"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10",
                      "100563691"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "id": "ShiptoInc_161185"
              },
              {
                "keys": [
                  "Payer_SalesArea",
                  "Payer_Id"
                ],
                "businessEntities": [
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10",
                      "960004763"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "id": "Payer_161185"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "UID": "d9f2b591f58e4aeebaa0b88175d4fe3c",
      "groups": {
        "organizations": [
          {
            "businessModels": [
              {
                "keys": [
                  "Company Code",
                  "Sales Org",
                  "Distribution Channel",
                  "Division"
                ],
                "businessEntities": [
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50",
                      "HU50_HU50",
                      "HU50_HU50_10",
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "id": "SalesArea_161185"
              },
              {
                "keys": [
                  "ShiptoInc_SalesArea",
                  "ShiptoInc_Id"
                ],
                "businessEntities": [
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10",
                      "100563692"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10",
                      "100563691"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "id": "ShiptoInc_161185"
              },
              {
                "keys": [
                  "Payer_SalesArea",
                  "Payer_Id"
                ],
                "businessEntities": [
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10",
                      "960004763"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "id": "Payer_161185"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "UID": "74a9ccbc9b8549d1a7726ac1f77f7ea9",
      "groups": {
        "organizations": [
          {
            "businessModels": [
              {
                "keys": [
                  "ShiptoInc_SalesArea",
                  "ShiptoInc_Id"
                ],
                "businessEntities": [
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10",
                      "100563692"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "id": "ShiptoInc_161185"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "UID": "d5ed356a3c2a48568ccacb8d9c7c5506",
      "groups": {
        "organizations": [
          {
            "businessModels": [
              {
                "keys": [
                  "Company Code",
                  "Sales Org",
                  "Distribution Channel",
                  "Division"
                ],
                "businessEntities": [
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50",
                      "HU50_HU50",
                      "HU50_HU50_10",
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "id": "SalesArea_161185"
              },
              {
                "keys": [
                  "ShiptoInc_SalesArea",
                  "ShiptoInc_Id"
                ],
                "businessEntities": [
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10",
                      "100563692"
                    ]
                  },
                                    {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_20_20",
                      "100563692"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10",
                      "100563691"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "id": "ShiptoInc_161185"
              },
              {
                "keys": [
                  "Payer_SalesArea",
                  "Payer_Id"
                ],
                "businessEntities": [
                  {
                    "codes": [
                      "HU50_HU50_10_10",
                      "960004763"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "id": "Payer_161185"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "objectsCount": 4,
  "totalCount": 4
}
```

For a known id ("Payer_161185" or "ShiptoInc_161185") and a given value ("100563692") we need to extract all repetitions of businessEntities.codes of all UIDs and after get the list, remove duplicates.

For example, for "ShiptoInc_161185", the desired output would be:

```
{ "salesAreas": ["HU50_HU50_10_10","HU50_HU50_20_20"]}
```

This output is the list of salesAreas for the given value 100563692 into all the id = ShiptoInc_161185

Other case that I would like to solve is:

How could I add the id instead of text salesAreas?. Something like this {"Payer_111":["HU50_HU50_10_10","HU50_HU50_30_20"],"Payer_222":["HU40_HU40_10_10","HU20_HU20_30_20"]}. This means the id wouldn't be provided, just the prefix Payer_

Your help is appreciated.

***I solved the second requirement

```
def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body);


    def bModelsIdFiltered = data.results.groups.organizations.businessModels      
            .collect { it[0] }.flatten()               
            .findAll { it.id.contains('Payer_') }


    def nList = [];
    def rembM = bModelsIdFiltered.each{
        it.businessEntities.codes.each { code ->
            nList.add(code.plus(it.id))
        }
    }



    println "nl " + nList;


    def codesFiltered = nList
            .findAll { '100563692' in it }


    

    return codesFiltered;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure is rigid and i understood the task correctly (namely, you should find codes that have value `100563692` in the same array), you can doing it like that:

```
class FindCodesSpec extends Specification {
    def testString = '''<insert_your_string_here>'''

    def flattenOnce(List array) {
        return array.inject([]) { res, el -> res + el }
    }

    def findCodes(String message, String id, String code) {
        def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(message)

        def bModelsIdFiltered = data.results.groups.organizations.businessModels
                .collect { it[0] }.flatten()
                .findAll { it.id == id }

        def codesFiltered = flattenOnce(bModelsIdFiltered.businessEntities.codes)
                .findAll { code in it }

        def uniqueCodes = codesFiltered.flatten().unique() - code
        return JsonOutput.toJson(['salesAreas': uniqueCodes])
    }

    def 'run test'() {
        expect:
        '''{"salesAreas":["HU50_HU50_10_10","HU50_HU50_20_20"]}''' == findCodes(testString, 'ShiptoInc_161185', '100563692')
    }
}
```

Comment: One more doubt, how could I add the id instead of text salesAreas?. Something like this {"Payer_111":["HU50_HU50_10_10","HU50_HU50_30_20"],"Payer_222":["HU40_HU40_10_10","HU20_HU20_30_20"]}. This means the id wouldn't be provided, just the prefix Payer_